# Very old Ubuntu release., want to override

Tags: usb

I installed an Ubuntu release 3-4 years ago in my Asus eeePC, and now I want a clean installation of the latest Ubuntu release since I got lot of problems (I cannot not even connect to my wifi LAN at home). I downloaded the .iso file into a USB but the eeePC cannot boot from the USB, could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: go to the link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation maybe there you can find something that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

i have never done that, but i found an instruction for you :

[installation from USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Answer (score 0):

Did you just straight download the .iso file to the usb? If that is the case it will not boot since the .iso file itself is not bootable. You will need to use a program like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or if you have Windows installed anywhere you could use [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/). Both of these programs are easy to use and will create a bootable liveUSB.

Hopefully that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks, since it's a really old version of Ubuntu I tried the USB disk creator from the synaptic package manager, and also tried another USB disc creatgor for windows y my windows laptop, but when trying to boot the eeePC from USB, I get the message "Reboot and select proper Boot device, or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key". Could you please help again? Thanks!

Comment: Did you reformat the USB to fat32? Have you used this usb for bootable media before and does the usb port work with other usb devices. Also where did you get the iso from?

Comment: I got the iso file from ubuntu web page. I formatted the USB to FAT32 in my windows laptop, although I created the bootable file and teied to boot from the eeePC where I have an old version of Ubuntu and try to reinstall the newest one from scratch. Should I format to fat32 in the eeePC using the old ubuntu? How to do that? Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you format the USB. Once it is formatted it's formatted. Have you tried a different usb or a different live usb creator? If you have, it would be helpful to edit your initial question to include the USB creator you used and some other info like if you have tried several different usbs and if you have tried using a live cd/dvd. From what you have told me so far, it seems like you have done the live usb and installation process correctly so I am wondering if it is a problem with the usb itself or the usb port on your computer.